# Allocating an array in a templated class

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

The template I'm using is

```
template<typename T, size_type MAX_DIM = 500>
```

I am trying to figure out how to allocate correctly. 
The variable T ** array_ is declared in the constructor.
This is what I have right now, but I've tried a few different kinds of syntax to no avail.

```
array_=new value_type*[dim1_];
    for ( long i = 0u; i < dim1_; i++)
        array_[i] = new value_type[dim2_];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using `value_type` when the template argument is `T` just use it:

```
template<typename T, size_t MAX_SIZE = 500>
class MyArray
{
    T** array_;
public:
    MyArray(size_t dim1_, size_t dim2)
    {
        array_ = new T*[dim1_];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
          array_[i] = new T[dim2];
    }
};
```

Mind that since you are not using `std::vector` nor `std::array` you will need to release memory manually through `delete []` in the destructor.

Comment: typo in the loop, should be `i < dim1_`